# Need to select all the Null value records and email them back to the sender but batch upload the rest of the correctly filled resords

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

If i have a table that on occasion has columns account, dim1,dim2,description,aparid with Null values, but the other records with correctly filled data.

How do I go about extracting these fields with Null values but upload the rest of the data into a batch input system.

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms, `is null` and `is not null`?

Comment: I used 'Is Null' to extract the following image out

Answer (score 0):

SQL query below returns two results: 
First - with rows where are no Null values;
Second - rows having at least one Null value;

```
-- Table variable to store KeyIds
DECLARE @KeyTbl table(KeyID bigint)

-- Collecting KeyId's of rows where is no Null values 
INSERT INTO @KeyTbl 
SELECT batch_id FROM Test 
    WHERE account IS NOT NULL 
        AND dim_1 is not NULL 
        AND dim_2 is not NULL 
        AND description IS NOT NULL 
        AND apar_id IS NOT NULL;

-- All rows where are no Null values 
SELECT Test.* FROM @KeyTbl Keys
INNER JOIN  Test 
    ON Test.batch_id = Keys.KeyID;

-- Rows having Null values
SELECT Test.* FROM @KeyTbl Keys
RIGHT JOIN  Test 
    ON Test.batch_id = Keys.KeyID
WHERE Keys.KeyID IS NULL;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3757b/3)